# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'

Tags: cpu

I have query to calcuate CPU usage and need to copy the output to table but getting the error

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

Please find the query.

```
Insert into dbo.cpudata([database],[system cpu],[database cpu],[%],[Date&time])
DECLARE @total INT
SELECT @total=sum(cpu) FROM sys.sysprocesses sp (NOLOCK)
join sys.sysdatabases sb (NOLOCK) ON sp.dbid = sb.dbid
SELECT sb.name 'database', @total 'system cpu', SUM(cpu) 'database cpu', CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,1), CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),SUM(cpu)) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),@total)*100) '%', GETDATE () as [Date&time]
FROM sys.sysprocesses sp (NOLOCK)
JOIN sys.sysdatabases sb (NOLOCK) ON sp.dbid = sb.dbid
--WHERE sp.status = 'runnable'
GROUP BY sb.name
ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,1), CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),SUM(cpu)) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),@total)*100) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you move to statement which populates @total above the insert.

```
DECLARE @total INT
SELECT @total=sum(cpu) FROM sys.sysprocesses sp (NOLOCK)
join sys.sysdatabases sb (NOLOCK) ON sp.dbid = sb.dbid
Insert into dbo.cpudata([database],[system cpu],[database cpu],[%],[Date&time])
...............
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `DECLARE` a variable in the middle of an `INSERT` statement. You've done so, between the `INSERT INTO <columnlist>` and `SELECT <columnlist>`.

Move the declaration above the start of the `INSERT` instead.